# pod "Setting up CocoaPods master repo" everytime I use "pod install"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, cocoapods-app

I already have a Cocoapods master repo! But this is always happening. I already reinstalled this more than 10 times!

By the way OS is EL Capitan 10.11.6 and my Cocoapods is 1.0.1.

Please help. I can't get my Xcode 8 project to work.

Comment: Your question is vague and its not possible to understand your issue with the given brief. Can you please post the exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my first installation, I got the same problem too, it takes too much time in "setting up master repo". 
Try these following steps, it solves my problem:

```
1. pod setup
```

It will do " setting up master " again, don't wait, continue these steps below

```
2. Ctrl +C
3. pod repo remove master
4. cd ~/.cocoapods/repos 
5. git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

It takes around 5 minutes for me (I think it depends on internet connection), then I can do "pod install".

Comment: This Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps

1. close the xcode.
2. delete the pods and reinstall.
3. open the xcode.

it may be buggy sometimes when u reinstall pods by opening the xcode